# qr code whatsapp vba

Tags: selenium, ms-access, vba

Good morning I would need to know how I can resume the saved log of whatsapp with selenium. I would like to avoid scanning the qr code every time I start the software.

At the end of this code to start sending I have to scan the qr. How do I get the firefox profile saved?

```
Private Sub Comando0_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
    Dim bot As New FirefoxDriver
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT idcontatto,cellulare,msg,allegato FROM selectname")
    Dim valore As String
    Dim numcell As String
    Dim alleg As String

    bot.get "https://web.whatsapp.com"
```

Comment: That scanning is a security measure and will also be required after periods of inactivity. I doubt it is something you can simply save and bypass though I could be wrong.

Comment: But on all browsers, including Firefox, the whatsapp connection remains stored until you disconnect the PC from the app

Comment: Selenium would open a fresh browser instance. What happens when you open FF and navigate to the webpage? I assume it asks for you to make a connection again? Does the same not happen even if you opened the webpage is a new browser tab manually?

Comment: when I open the firefox web page not from selenium the connection is already recognized. And this I believe because access is stored in the profiles. In your opinion, how can I switch profiles to selenium?